# How to deploy a project on Dokku without using Git remote

Tags: deployment, dokku

How can I deploy a project without using Git On Dokku? I read the [documentation](https://dokku.com/docs/deployment/methods/archive/) on how to deply a project using a compressed file or using Docker. But both ways require Git to initialize the project.

`dokku git:from-archive node-js-app https://github.com/dokku/smoke-test-app/releases/download/2.0.0/smoke-test-app.tar`

Is there any solution to ignore Git initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the app via `dokku apps:create app-name` and run the respective git:from-archive or git:from-image command. Dokku will internally download the archive or pull the image and handle any git operations on your behalf, so there is no need for you to perform any actions otherwise.

The commands are in the git namespace purely for organizational reasons.